# Can I get createSagaMiddleware using require?

Tags: node.js, redux-saga

I'm trying to use run sagas in an a node app that will run from the command line: `node app.js`

I can't use import, so I'm trying to get createSagaMiddleware using require:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
```

I get this error:

"TypeError: createSagaMiddleware is not a function"

Can Saga be used like this?

```
const { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } = require("redux");
const createSagaMiddleware  = require("redux-saga");
const {  take } = require("redux-saga/effects");

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const reducer = state => state;

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

function* watcherSaga() {
    yield take("START");
    yield //do stuff
}

sagaMiddleware.run(watcherSaga)

store.dispatch({type: 'START'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const createSagaMiddleware  = require("redux-saga").default;
```